# Having trouble saving image to entity field on IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

On my server I have a table that I want to get over to IOS sqllite table.

My server table has a field called data which is of type Image. The way I populated the field is that I wrote a C# app that converts an image to byte array and then write this byte array to sql Image column.

In IOS, I make a soap request to my wcf service and get all data from my table. I made sure data is received. My problem is writing received image data to my entity's binary data field. I use the following code for that.

```
NSString *key = (NSString *) [keys objectAtIndex:i]; // I made sure key is valid
NSData *data = (NSData *) [rowData GetValue:key];  // I made sure data is retrieved

[tblRow setValue:data forKey:key];  // After calling this, data for the key is nil.
```

Portion of Image Data Content

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

Comment: I think we need more information about this. What are you exactly using on the iOS side? NSManangedObject or another?

Comment: Then you are not saving the image correctly. THat NSManagedObject has to have a field that is called let's say "image" and you set it like this :  managedObject.image = nsdataimage; then you get the context from the managedObject :     NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObject.managedObjectContext;
   
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }. And then the field it's updated in the SQLite table.

Comment: What's wrong with using [tblRow setValue:data forKey:key];?

Comment: It won't save like that, if you need an example of how to insert/update into a SQLite database using NSManagedObjectContext then let me know and I'll provide you with one.

Comment: Okay provide an example.

Comment: I think you got it okay with the [tblRow setValue:data forKey:key]; if the tblRow is an NSManageObject and if you save it with the NSManagedContext like I wrote above .

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial on how it needs to be saved.Not that complete but it should give you the idea.[tutorial here](http://mikeahmarani.com/?tag=Tutorial)

Comment: Just for testing, what do you get doing `[tblRow setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];` and then `NSString *value = [tblRow valueForKey:@"key"]`?

Comment: If `key` and `data` are both valid and the assignment doesn't occur properly, maybe `tblRow` is `nil`, so passing a message to it won't throw an exception or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not the one writing the WCF Service that sends me the image data and I learned that the service applies base 64 encoding to the data and setting base 64 string to NSData object and trying to save it was failing. Once I decoded the data, everything worked fine.